# Minimums of symmetric functions

Tags: symmetric-functions

In this problem

[minimize a function using AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980875/minimize-a-function-using-am-gm-inequality/980892#980892)

we discussed about the minimum points of a simmetric function.
Now I would like to ask to you this:

If you have a rational function $f(x,y)$ that is simmetric in the two variables, meaning $f(x,y)\equiv f(y,x)$, then is it always true that the point of minimum/maximum, if there exist, are such that $x=y$?

In the case $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$, the partial derivatives tell me that there exist critical point with $x=y$, but are they of minimum/maximum? and are thay all the minimums/maximums?

And in the case $f(x,y)=g(x)g(y)$ or, in general, when you can "saparate" in some way the two variables?

And when there's a simmetric polynomial constraint $h(x,y)=c\in\mathbb{R} $?

Comment: Symmetric problems have symmetric solution *sets*, but it's not always the case that the individual solutions are symmetric.  E.g., maximize $x^2+y^2$ subject to $|x|+|y|\le 1$.  (Or, subject to $(x+y)^{100}+(x-y)^{100}\le 1$ if you insist on polynomial constraints.)

Comment: @StevenTaschuk can you find some example with a finite number of minimums non simmetric?

Comment: Minimize $x^2+y^2$ subject to the constraint that $(x,y)$ lie on the boundary of a regular octagon with vertices $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for $\theta=\frac{2\pi n}{8}$.

Comment: Or, take the square $[-1,1]^2$ and cut a tiny bit off at each of the corners, and optimize over the boundary.  Then the minimum of $x^2+y^2$ is at $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$ and the maximum is close to, but not exactly at, $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$.

Comment: Ok, you can play with boundary and find suh examples, but this time I'll try to be more specific: there exist a polynomial simmetric function defined on the unitary ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that it has a finite number of non-simmetric minimums in the interior of the ball?

Comment: Can't I just pick any desired minima $(m_i)_{i=1}^k$ and define $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^k \|x-m_i\|^2$ ?  If the set of minima is symmetric under permutation of coordinates, this polynomial will be too.